# Determination of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, pi

How to prove

$$
\frac{\sqrt{8}}{9801}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(4n)!(1103+26390n)}{(n!)^4 396^{4n}}=\frac{1}{\pi},
$$

which actually looks like coincidence?

Comment: Nothing is a coincidence in math

Comment: @mathworker21 Not even $\pi^4+\pi^5≈e^6$? (It's ridiculously close.)

Comment: @timtfj you never know. here is an explanation for why $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ is very close to an integer. http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/ramanujanconstant.pdf

Comment: @mathworker21 The first sentence is somewhat startling in itself. "Ramanujan observed that [*insane calculation*]"

Comment: If you want the proof then you have to understand that it's really difficult. The conceptual ideas can be grasped with some effort but evaluation of the constant $1103$ in your formula is very difficult.